# MySql запрос на групирование товаров по артиклю

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно сделать запрос, что бы получить следующее.
Есть товары, у которых одинаковый артикул. Сейчас вывожу обычным селектом:

```
Select * From products
```

Выводятся все товары с одинаковым артикулем.
А как вывести только один товар если Артикул одинаковый? т.е. если в бд есть еще один товар с таким же артикулом то вывести его один раз.

Comment: *как вывести только один товар если Артикул одинаковый?* Какой именно из нескольких?

Comment: выводи товар по id